# libgdx how to add clicklistener at images

Tags: java, image, libgdx, listener

I just started to prototype with libGDX to understand how it works.
I want to realize a grid (like chess game) and when I click/touch a box of the grid, this change its image.

I've found a good tutorial, but it only use the keyboard listener and on web I can't find a good example that clarify to me the these mechanics.

What i don't understand is essentially: what use to render the boxes (for now I've used only SpriteBatch and ShapeRenderer) and how detect when e which box was clicked (I think that calculate coordinates not was a good way to follow. I imagine that best way is add a click listener at each box to determine when it will clicked, but I don't know how to code this).

Thanks for any suggestion, if you have an example, it can help me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Image image = new Image();

image.addListener(new ClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        System.out.println("You clicked an image...");
    }
});
```

Now we can add this image to something like a `Table` or directly to the `Stage`.

Like dtx12 has mentioned you should look into [Scene2D](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d). You probably want to setup a grid using a table like so.

```
Table chessTable = new Table();
int boardHeight = 8;
int boardWidth = 8;

for (int y = 0; y < boardHeight; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < boardWidth; x++)
    {
        //Check if dividable by two to make checker pattern and add cell to table.
        if (x + y % 2 == 0)
            chessTable.add(blackImage);
        else 
            chessTable.add(whiteImage);
    }
    //Add a new row to table
    chessTable.row();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, your example combined with this scene2d tutorial: [link](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/11/27/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-1.aspx) have explained how works clickListener. To be honest I still not have understood how render the Table's contents, but not is needed for my example of game.

Comment: @newUser.java Well the stage handles drawing for you. You add the Table to the stage and in the update method you simple call stage.draw(). But in order to properly understand you should indeed read some more about `Scene2D` and perhaps do a tutorial on the subject there are plenty around. If my answer is what you are looking for consider accepting it and gain 2 rep in the process ;).

Answer (score 0):

Scene2d is the best for your purposes, check documentation.
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d

You may add `ActorGestureListener` to created actor for example.
For rendering something using `ShapeRenderer` you may override actor's `draw` method
and apply matrix to them. But would be better to have simple image with rectangle instead of using `ShapeRenderer` if you only need to draw boxes. Select variant which you like more.

Comment: Although the question is very low level we should not just link to documentation. At least copy some of the documentation in your question besides the link for the source.